# Learning math with gamification

Tags: windows, learning

I am looking for a math game to learn

- addition
- subtraction
- multiplication
- division

for grades 1 to 4, i.e. beginning with numbers from 1 through 10 and advancing to the range 1...1 million.

For the lower value ranges, it should have a time-mode, i.e. the sooner you answer, the more points you get.

Learning should be gamified, e.g.

- getting points or stars
- learning streaks (e.g. 5 days of learning)
- comparison with others (might be fake)
- use of virtual money (credits) to unlock new features

I know a similar "game" for learning languages, called [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/), which is quite nice.

The software should work on Windows ideally, but a browser-based game would be ok as well.

Price: [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) is great, but I would pay up to 20 €.

Comment: Tag suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Have u tried [Luminosity](https://www.lumosity.com/en/). In addition to Math, they have plenty of brain games